# Firebase DB snapshot.val() returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using the `firebase-admin (5.13.1)` NodeJS library, and am having trouble getting `.val()` to work on a `.on('value')` function.

```
  var key = "someFirebaseKey";
  db.ref().child('search/response').child(key).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  })
```

This returns `null`.

However, `snapshot` has values:

```
DataSnapshot {
  node_: 
   ChildrenNode {
     children_: 
      SortedMap {
        comparator_: [Function: NAME_COMPARATOR],
        root_: LLRBEmptyNode {} },
     priorityNode_: null,
     indexMap_: IndexMap { indexes_: [Object], indexSet_: [Object] },
     lazyHash_: '' },
  ref_: 
   Reference {
     repo: 
      Repo {
        repoInfo_: [RepoInfo],
        app: [FirebaseApp],
        dataUpdateCount: 2,
        statsListener_: null,
        eventQueue_: [EventQueue],
        nextWriteId_: 3,
        interceptServerDataCallback_: null,
        onDisconnect_: [SparseSnapshotTree],
        persistentConnection_: [PersistentConnection],
        stats_: [StatsCollection],
        server_: [PersistentConnection],
        statsReporter_: [StatsReporter],
        transactionQueueTree_: [Tree],
        infoData_: [SnapshotHolder],
        infoSyncTree_: [SyncTree],
        serverSyncTree_: [SyncTree],
        __database: [Database] },
     path: Path { pieces_: [Array], pieceNum_: 0 },
     queryParams_: 
      QueryParams {
        limitSet_: false,
        startSet_: false,
        startNameSet_: false,
        endSet_: false,
        endNameSet_: false,
        limit_: 0,
        viewFrom_: '',
        indexStartValue_: null,
        indexStartName_: '',
        indexEndValue_: null,
        indexEndName_: '',
        index_: PriorityIndex {} },
     orderByCalled_: false },
  index_: PriorityIndex {} }
```

Any ideas on direction or how to go about debugging the Firebase object?

I've spent the last day and a half on trying to fix this, tried several different debugging attempts, read most of the StackOverflow threads on this, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) returns null when there's no data at the location of the query:

> Depending on the data in a DataSnapshot, the val() method may return a
>   scalar type (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object. It
>   may also return null, indicating that the DataSnapshot is empty
>   (contains no data).

The internal contents of the DataSnapshot object are not to be used directly.  Use the public API instead.

Comment: "The internal contents of the DataSnapshot object are not to be used directly. Use the public API instead." - Can you please elaborate your statement?

Comment: @MartinBraun All that means is that you shouldn't dig around in the properties of the snapshot that are not documented, or your code is likely to break.

Comment: Alright, got it. For some reason I get null, even when the data clearly exists. I don't know why.

Comment: Further investigation shows that I am unable to receive the value when there are more children in the tree. Maybe you can have a look? I would appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925617/snapshot-will-have-no-value-when-there-are-more-children-in-the-hierarchy