# Firebase Realtime Database data snapshot will have no value when there are more children in the hierarchy

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have a node.js server application that uses `firebase-admin` (<s>8.13.0</s> 9.9.0) to access the realtime database (legacy) of Firebase, but there is an issue. It cannot receive a specific snapshot's value when there is more than one child in the target sub tree. At least I think this is the symptom of the problem.

Please see this sample data:

[image: Sample firebase data]

All of the objects above are populated.

And this is the code (server.js):

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var http = require("http");
setting_detail = {};

init();

function init() {
    var pkg = require('./package.json');

    var config = require('./config/config'),
        mongoose = require('./config/mongoose'),
        express = require('./config/express'),
        db = mongoose(),
        app = express();
    const port = '8000';
    app.listen(port);

    var Setting = require('mongoose').model('setting');
    Setting.findOne({}, function (error, setting) {

        setting_detail = setting
        var admin = require("firebase-admin");
        var serviceAccount = {
            "type": setting_detail.type,
            "project_id": setting_detail.project_id,
            "private_key_id": setting_detail.private_key_id,
            "private_key": setting_detail.private_key,
            "client_email": setting_detail.client_email,
            "client_id": setting_detail.client_id,
            "auth_uri": setting_detail.auth_uri,
            "token_uri": setting_detail.token_uri,
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": setting_detail.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
            "client_x509_cert_url": setting_detail.client_x509_cert_url
        };

        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
            databaseURL: setting_detail.databaseURL
        });

        admin.database().ref("6017a15dd78fa359be7aa28c").child("24").once("value", function(snapshot) {
                var test = snapshot.val();
                console.log(test); // will print an object
        });

        admin.database().ref("601a72368fd78074daa977c8").child("24").once("value", function(snapshot) {
                var test = snapshot.val();
                console.log(test); // will print null
        });

        admin.database().ref("601a8c9e8fd78074daa977e1").child("23").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
                var test = snapshot.val();
                console.log(test); // will print null, even on promises
        });

        admin.database().ref("601a8c9e8fd78074daa977e1").child("24").once("value", function(snapshot) {
                var test = snapshot.val();
                console.log(test); // will print null
        });

    });
    exports = module.exports = app;
}
```

*serviceAccount* contents:

```
auth_provider_x509_cert_url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'
auth_uri:'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
client_email:'firebase-adminsdk-*****@store-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
client_id:'109******************'
client_x509_cert_url:'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-*****%40store-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
private_key:'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n********************************************************************************************\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
private_key_id:'f23*************************************'
project_id:'store-******'
token_uri:'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
type:'service_account'
```

Console output:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:55737) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:55737) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:55737) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
Magic happens on port 8000
{
  '-M_NSc1jcXv3hWDB5R0q': {
    chat_type: 24,
    id: '-M_NSc1jcXv3hWDB5R0q',
    is_notify: false,
    is_read: false,
    message: 'hallo',
    receiver_id: '60178ed135de8657dfb67a8b',
    sender_type: 4,
    time: '2021-05-10T22:47:11.810Z'
  }
}
null
null
null
```

I also tried to use strings instead of numbers (i.e. `"23"` or `"24"` instead of `23` or `24`), but the result was the same.

I'm new to Firebase, so this is very confusing to me. What is the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Your code looks ok really. Can you try only the second query to see what will happen? (disabling other three). And you may update to latest firebase-admin.

Comment: @Er.Se I tested each call, individually, and I also updated firebase-admin to version 9.9.0, the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes your problem, because there is many possibilities.
However, try this and see what you get (and your realtime structure won't cause like this problems, the problem most likely in the reading way) :

```
admin.database().ref().child('601a72368fd78074daa977c8')
                .child('24')
                .once('value')
                .then((data) => { 
                   final test = data.val();
                   console.log(test);
                 });
```

if still not working, please provide more of your code, and see if you get any error or logs on the server or the console.

Comment: Unfortunately, using promises won't help. I edited my question to provide the full server.js that includes the test as well as the console output. Is it possible that credentials have only permission to specific children? Are there any configurations in Firebase that could cause such issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
const somefun = async () => {
        const snap1 = await database().ref("6017a15dd78fa359be7aa28c/24").once('value');
        const snap2 = await database().ref("601a72368fd78074daa977c8/24").once('value');
        const snap3 = await database().ref("601a8c9e8fd78074daa977e1/24").once('value');
    
        console.log(snap1.toJSON())
        console.log(snap2.toJSON())
        console.log(snap2.toJSON())
}
```

Using Promises instead of callbacks helped me solve some annoying problems with firebase.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tested it with promises, but it did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @MartinBraun check out if data is available if you use Firebase REST API check this answer for ref. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979394/get-specific-data-from-firebase-rest-api/67979592#67979592

Comment: In the key `601a72368fd78074daa977c8` there is a child `24`. Its snapshot will be null and its child has two data entries, `-MSbRMAMvfF6ouGHOxRZ` and `-MSbXzGBZjytmEVztUHw`. Despite being unable to load the data using the admin SDK, I can access the data with the JSON link without problems, so the data is available, but cannot be load from the SDK.