# get specific data from Firebase REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rest

I'm learning about reactJS and for the database I'm using firebase realtime Database.. everything works. but there is one problem..

i have Firebase url like this

```
https://my-app-name-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/data.json
```

and the result when get the data

```
{
  "data" : {
    "-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e" : {
      "data" : {
        "authorized" : {...},
        "authorizedFinance" : {...},
        "authorizedTechnical" : {...},
        "billingAddress" : {...},
        "information" : {...},
        "serviceOrder" : {...},
        "subscriptionFee" : {...},
        "typeofOrder" : {...}
      }
    },
    "-Mc9XCIdCg4FLDzj3Xmg" : {
      "data" : {
        "authorized" : {...},
        "authorizedFinance" : {...},
        "authorizedTechnical" : {...},
        "billingAddress" : {...},
        "information" : {...},
        "serviceOrder" : {...},
        "subscriptionFee" : {...},
        "typeofOrder" : {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what i want is,just get 1 data by the id `-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e`.

```
{
  "data" : {
    "-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e" : {
      "data" : {
        "authorized" : {...},
        "authorizedFinance" : {...},
        "authorizedTechnical" : {...},
        "billingAddress" : {...},
        "information" : {...},
        "serviceOrder" : {...},
        "subscriptionFee" : {...},
        "typeofOrder" : {...}
      }
    }
 }
```

[image: fireabse]

i have tried to pass params in the url like this

```
https://my-app-name-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/data.json?id=-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e
```

but is not working. i get the all data..

so, how to do it? is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can navigate through the child nodes in the Realtime Database console by clicking on nodes

It provides a URL for the node you want to access and append `.json` at last to access it. Make sure your rules and authentication are synced.

So required link would be :

`https://my-app-name-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebaseio.com/data/-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e.json`

Ref:

[image]

[image: Realtime database - nodes navigation to get link]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL to get just that specific key is:

https://my-app-name-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/data/-Mc8l24sBroFw8JoA32e.json

So the `.json` is last, and before that you have the entire path to the data that you want to retrieve.